# How to install Python packages on Azure Batch Node

Tags: python, azure-batch

I am following the MS Azure Batch tutorial for Python: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-python-tutorial

Now, I want to use some non-standard Python packages, such as SciPy or Colorama... whatever.

for example:

```
import scipy
import colorama
import ...
```

I cannot find any information on this by MS. 
Also, how do I make my VM node use python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install any arbitrary software you like on your virtual machine, you can use the [StartTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-batch/azure.batch.models.starttask?view=azure-python) object in the [PoolAddParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-batch/azure.batch.models.pooladdparameter?view=azure-python) object when you call add the pool to your account via [add](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-batch/azure.batch.operations.pooloperations?view=azure-python) within the pool operations.

There are also a few alternatives:

1. Use [application packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-application-packages)
2. Use [containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-docker-container-workloads)
3. Bring your own [custom image](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-custom-images)

Regarding how to use `python3` on the VM. That is not an Azure Batch specific issue, you'll need to figure out how to do that within the distribution/operating system specific way. For instance, if using Ubuntu, one possibility would be to ensure you have done the proper `apt-get` calls to retrieve the libraries and binaries required.

Comment: Thanks, I actually just figured this out.